# Async request function never finishes executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have a function in an AWS Lambda function that runs fine by the node command in AWS Cloud9, but fails when run locally on Docker-Lambda. The function in question is below, console.logs with a "!" prefix are successfully logged. Those without are not.

```
async function getCoworkerById(id) {
    console.log('!*several enter getCoworkerById');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('!*several enter getCoworkerById Promise');
        request({
            url: 'https://spaces.nexudus.com/api/spaces/coworkers',
            qs: {
                Coworker_Id: id
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(process.env.nexudusEmail + ':' + process.env.nexudusPassword, 'utf8').toString('base64')
            }
        }, (error, response, body) => {
            console.log("enter getCoworkerById 2");
            if (error) {
                console.log("enter getCoworkerById error");
                reject(error);
            } else {
                console.log("enter getCoworkerById response");
                if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                    console.log('recieved 200 from getcoworkerbyid')
                    resolve(JSON.parse(body).Records[0]);
                } else if (response.statusCode === 409) {
                    console.log('recieved 409 from getcoworkerbyid')
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        resolve(getCoworkerById(id));
                    }, response.headers['Retry-After'] * 1000);
                } else {
                    reject(response);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The function is called in this block, notice that I'm using the async library:

```
const coworkerPromises = [];
async.eachLimit(coworkerIds, 3, (id, callback) => {
  console.log('!*several enter each limit');
  try {
    console.log('!*several enter each limit try');
    coworkerPromises.push(getCoworkerById(id));
    callback();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error getting coworker by ID: ', e);
  }
});
try {
  Promise.all(coworkerPromises).then(coworkers => {
    console.log("Enter promise all");
    console.log(coworkers[coworkers.length - 1]);
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

This one has me really stumped. Why would we never get to the second half of the function without an error or anything?

Comment: What's bizarre to me is that this ran perfectly in node on Cloud9 (both use node8.10), so it doesn't seem like a case of this pattern just not working with async. Or am I wrong? Also I tried it without the 'async' and still no dice. :/

Comment: I think `coworkerPromises` will be empty at `Promise.all(coworkerPromises)` - because it is being "populated" in an asynchronous callback `async.eachLimit(coworkerIds, 3, (id, callback) => {` - so, you should be getting `console.log("Enter promise all");` output at least

Comment: however, the fact that none of the console.logs in `request` callback are called seems very odd indeed - I take it you are using `async` library for the rate limiting?

Comment: maybe you should use `Promise.all(coworkerPromises).then( .....).catch(e => console.error(e))` then you'll see if a promise has been rejected (rather than try/catch because that won't catch a promise rejection)

Comment: I console logged coworkerPromises right after the .push statement, as well as its length, and got 103 Promise { <pending> }'s. What do you think this means? Will try that catch now.

Comment: that means there's 103 pending promises in the array - another thing ... put `console.log(coworkerPromises.length)` just before the second try block - almost guarantee that will output `0`

Comment: Tried the catch with a log and got nothing. Console logged coworkerPromises.length where you said and got 103. When I logged coworkerPromises[0] at the same place I got [object Promise].

Comment: really? didn't think `async` was blocking (I'm sure it isn't)

Comment: Just reran, same result. Here's the updated block: https://pastebin.com/raw/YGnZQw5k

Comment: you're not stepping through the code with some sort of debugger are you? I find it unlikely that, given the code in the question, `coworkerPromises` is anything but an empty array at the point of executing `Promise.all` - but then, as I said - `async` **library** + `promises` === trouble

Comment: is the `async.eachLimit(coworkerIds, 3` something that limits the code to 3 "parallel" requests at a time? because you won't get that limitation with the code you wrote - perhaps because you are throwing too many "parallel" operations at a time (i.e. **all of them**) it's causing breakages

Comment: Not stepping through a debugger. And to your second comment, yes, and that's how it worked when we tested it on Cloud9. Or at least we avoided the 409 onslaught and got every record we needed pulled successfully.

Comment: fair enough - see if this https://pastebin.com/xs4wafa4 makes any difference (note: does not use async library at all)

Comment: Tried it, and nothing additional was logged. The first two are logged but the rest are not. Agh, what could this possibly be?

Comment: the first two what are logged?

Comment: !*several enter getCoworkerById
and !*several enter getCoworkerById Promise

Comment: well ... what is `request`? does it take a callback function? because it looks like it does not - which would explain why the promise remains pending ... and `let test = request(... the rest of your request code ...)` ... then `console.log(test)` after (outside of) the callback code

Comment: Tried that and got "Error getting bookings:  TypeError: request(...).then is not a function"

Comment: No. The then wasn't a .then it was just to say after that add a console.log of test. But anyway.  What is the request function. Where is it from

Comment: The request npm module. Ah, sorry, my mistake. I logged and Json.parse'd test where you said and got: https://pastebin.com/GiBfqeVU

Comment: How long have you waited before terminating the container? Sounds like a timeout issue - perhaps the container's network isn't properly configured. There are a few timeouts to consider, DNS resolution timeouts, TCP connection timeouts and HTTP timeouts. DNS being the annoying one, as it's handled by the `c-ares` library and configuration need to be set via environment variables. But let the container run for a few minutes and see if you get a timeout error.

Comment: The code finishes executing after 12807.63 ms. I've had it run for upwards of five minutes without issue, so maybe it isn't a timeout issue? If it is its weird that it would only be manifesting in this scenario.

Comment: Finishes executing after ~13 seconds with no error or success? Most likely because the `try-catch`-block in your last snippet doesn't work. Add a `.catch(console.error)` after the `.then(coworkers => ...)`. Also, the function passed to `async.eachLimit` in your code does not do what you intend it to do, which is rate-limiting. So all your ~103 requests *will* execute at the same time. Could you clarify where your code does work and doesn't work? As I understand it, it works in AWS Lambda when deployed, but not in your local container `docker-lambda`. Is that right?

Comment: Added a .catch(console.error) where you said and it was never logged. I also pull other records earlier which probably accounts for a good bit of that 13 seconds